# Security of Diffie Hellman in specific cyclic group

Tags: diffie-hellman, prime-numbers

For some $k$, let's say $p = 1+ \prod_{j=1}^k q( j)$, where $q(1)=2$, $q(2)=3$,
if $p$ is prime, the diffie-hellman key exchange is not secure in cyclic group $Z^*_p$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime of the specified structure then the order of the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_p^*$ is $p-1=\prod_{j=1}^k q( j)$. As you may notice this is a product only consisting of small factors and thereby called *smooth*.

We actually know an attack on groups with smooth order, called [Pohlig-Hellman-Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) and the specified structure yields the optimal performance for that algorithm to compute discrete logarithms.